# Sending emails to separate accounts using a for loop

Tags: wp-cron, wp-mail

I need to run a for loop to go through all the users on my site and send any that are applicable an email.  A user can have several categories on their profile, let's say 4. If the customer has elected to receive emails, it then loops through their 4 categories.  I want to send them a unique email for each category.

This function works without the for loop.  If I remove it, I successfully receive an email for the first category.  As soon as I add that loop in, it fails and I don't get any email.

So two questions really - any suggestions on how to get the for loop to work?  And is there a log file for Cron jobs that I would be able to review?  I checked some plug-ins but can't find what I'm looking for.

Thank you!!

```
<?php
function check_user_tasks_week_before() {

    function set_html_content_type() {
        return 'text/html';
    }

    add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); //switches the emails to html
    $Number_of_Categories = 4;
    $user_info = get_userdata(1);

    if ($user_info->email_option == "Yes") {
        for ($z = 1; $z <= $Number_of_Categories; $z++) { //loop through each category      
            $subject = '';
            $message = '';
            $headers = 'From: Me <test@email.com>' . "\r\n";
            $subject = 'Email Reminder: ' . $user_info->category_1_step_1_category;
            ob_start();
            ?>
            <p>this is some info</p>
            <h1>this is a header</h1>
            <p>Here is a nice reminder for you <?php echo $user_info->user_login ?></p>
            <?php

            $message = ob_get_contents();

            ob_end_clean();

            wp_mail( 'test@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers);

        } //end for ($z = 1; $z <= $Number_of_Categories; $z++)
    } //end ($user_info->email_option == "Yes")

    remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' ); //switches the emails to text to avoid issues with other wp_mail() calls

} //end check_user_tasks_week_before
?>
```

Comment: You should debug the code by writing the log your self to a file and then verify if cron is running + loop is working + wp_email has correct email addresses etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion M-R!  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Just for an idea, you can use file_put_contents(date('Y-m-d').'.txt',$LOG_MESSAGE, FILE_APPEND).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, this part:

```
for ($z = 1; $z <= $Number_of_Categories; $z++)
```

is the offender.  even though $Number_of_Categories was defined above where it is used, the value wasn't holding.  I had to build a function instead, and do this:

```
function get_Number_of_Categories(){
  return "2";
}

for ($z = 1; $z <= get_Number_of_Categories(); $z++)
```

once I did that, the loop worked.